# Offensiveness of "black" in reference to race or skin colour

Tags: offensive-language

Is *black* offensive when used to refer to race or skin colour? If so, should we then not use *white* as well?

Comment: See "euphemism treadmill".

Comment: It seems to me it would be offensive if you used it in a sentence such as "He's a black." I think it would be less offensive if you said "He's black."

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Both *white* and *black* are widely considered to be inoffensive, and you hear them used over a wide range of contexts. Obviously, anyone can use any word in an offensive manner, and *black* is not exempt. Note that the word can also be written as *Black*.

Comment: Can, but never is.  Somehow that variant seems more offensive to me, perhaps because it is an explicit abstract categorization, whereas "black" is at least nominally just an adjective describing appearance.

Answer (score 43):

If I may quote [George Carlin](http://books.google.com/books?id=c-9ZAAAAMAAJ) again:

> First of all, I say "black." I say "black" because most people prefer
>   "black." I don't say "people of color." People of color sounds like
>   something you see when you're on mushrooms. Besides, the use of people
>   of color is dishonest. It means precisely the same as colored people.
>   If you're not willing to say "colored people," you shouldn't be saying
>   "people of color."
>
> Besides, the whole idea of color is bullshit anyway. What should we call
>   white people? "People of no color"? Isn't pink a color? In fact, white
>   people are not really white at all, they're different shades of pink,
>   olive, and beige. In other words, they're colored. And black people are
>   rarely black. I see mostly different shades of brown and tan. In fact, some
>   light-skinned black people are lighter than the darkest white people. Look
>   how dark the people in India are. They're dark brown, but they're
>   considered white people. What's going on here? May I see the color chart?
>   "People of color" is an awkward, bullshit, liberal-guilt phrase that
>   obscures meaning rather than enhancing it. Shall we call fat people, "people
>   of size"?
>
> ...
>
> I also don't say "African-American." I find it completely illogical, and
>   furthermore it's confusing. Which part of Africa are we talking about? What
>   about Egypt? Egypt is in Africa. Egyptians aren't black. They're like
>   the people in India, they're dark brown white people. But they're
>   Africans. So why wouldn't an Egyptian who becomes a U.S. citizen be an
>   African-American?
>
> The same thing goes for the Republic of South Africa. Suppose a white
>   racist from South Africa becomes an American citizen? Well, first of all
>   he'd find plenty of company, but couldn't he also be called an
>   African-American? It seems to me that a racist white South African guy could
>   come here and call himself African-American just to piss off
>   black people. And, by the way, what about a black person born in South
>   Africa who moves here and becomes a citizen? What is he? An African-South
>   African-American? Or a South African-African-American?
>
> All right, back to this hemisphere. How about a black woman who is a
>   citizen of Jamaica? According to P.C. doctrine, she's an African-American,
>   right? But if she becomes a U.S. citizen, she's Jamaican-American. And
>   yet if one of these language crusaders saw her on the street, he'd think she
>   was an African-American. ... It's just so much liberal bullshit.
>   **Labels divide people. We need fewer labels, not more.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Automatic +1 for quoting George Carlin. He is sorely missed.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but +1 because it made me laugh.

Comment: "Look how dark the people in India are. They're dark brown" not strictly accurate. Some people are, while many North Indians are fair, blue and green eyed, and can be red haired. What is it about Americans that make them assume they know everything?

Comment: @5arx, maybe you shouldn't judge a nation of 350 million people based on a sentence in a comedy routine.

Comment: Comedy routine? That's comedy ...?

Comment: @5arx, George Carlin was a stand-up comedian, and this quotation is from a book he wrote called *Brain Droppings*, which you will find in the humor section of a bookstore.

Comment: @5arx: LOL snap!

Comment: I am a white guy, in the U.S. I attend a church that is predominantly black. I hear them refer to people as "light skinned" and "dark skinned". But I find that vague because while "light skinned" could certainly apply to me, it might also apply to a medium toned negroid. (In less specific  contexts, one should avoid the word "negroid' too.)

Answer (score 12):

I'd use "black" to refer generally to people of sub-Saharan African descent.  "African-American" is a term that can confuse people; it's usual meaning is "descendent of pre-1865 black slaves in the USA", or a black person of other descent acculturated amongst slave-descendants.  It doesn't mean "any person of African descent who is an American citizen" (for example, Charlize Theron is not an African-American).  Recent black immigrants from Africa don't fit particularly comfortably into the "African-American" category, as they don't carry the culture.

It's a subset of black people.  Generally, African-Americans prefer to be referred to as such, rather than as black people (in the same way as I'd prefer to be referred to as "British" rather than "European").

Using black as a noun ("that man is a black") rather than an adjective ("that man is black") is often seen as less acceptable - one is a description, the other implies that it's a primary characteristic.

Black people in non-American countries are not often called *African-British or *African-French or whatever (we might get what you mean, but that's not a term anyone would use).  "Black British" has the nice benefit of alliteration that African-American has, and seems to be the preferred term.  As about half of the black people in Britain are immigrants (or descendents of immigrants)  from the Caribbean and about half are (more recent) immigrants (or their descendents) directly from Africa, geographical terms are generally seen as more specific - "African-British" might suggest "black, but not Afro-Caribbean", though, again, it's not used much because of the confusion.

Comment: +1 for being the only answerer that knows the meaning of "African-American."

Comment: +1 for the distinction between 'a black' and 'black' - referring to people as 'blacks' is definitely somewhat offensive IMO because, as you say, it makes skin colour the primary characteristic.

Comment: @tinyd: I agree. As a white American male, I have to say that I cannot recall hearing `a black` nor someone referring to people as `blacks` in a context that wasn't flat out racist in intent.

Comment: @horatio The same thing is operative in calling someone `a gay` instead of `gay`.  It’s somethingist, for some unpleasant value of *something*. It devalues the person.

Comment: @horatio I have, but it was my Granddad talking about the soldiers that served under his command in WWII.

Comment: It's even a bit more complicated: Barack Obama identifies as and is considered African American even though [his father](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama,_Sr.) was Kenyan rather than a descendant of slaves.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Yes, he was specifically who I was thinking of when I wrote "a black person of other descent acculturated amongst slave-descendants".  Like most communities, it can absorb immigrants.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is one answer that every group would universally agree with as their preferred term.  Some people prefer "African-American", some prefer "person of color", and some prefer "black".  I don't think most people would become overtly offended by everyday use of any of these terms, but some might consider one or more to be a pet peeve when they hear it.

Here is the history (via OED) of "African-American" and its rise in use:

> Although both African and African-American were widely used in the United States in the 19th century, the adoption of African-American as a preferred term among black Americans dates from the late 1960s and early 1970s (particularly after an April 1972 conference at which Ramona Edelin, president of the National Urban Coalition, proposed its use). The term gained widespread acceptance following its endorsement by the Reverend Jesse Jackson (b. 1941) during his presidential nomination campaign in 1988.

I think that non-American black people find this term ignorant at best when applied to them.  Also, sometimes immigrants who have east African ancestry don't feel that this term applies to them.  And other people of color just find it awkward, or simply have no problem with "black".

That said, even if you fall into the camp where you feel that "black" is an offensive term, it doesn't mean that the same must be true of "white".  Each word has a long history, and different associations get embedded in different words, such that superficially or logically corresponding words like "white person" and "black person" don't necessarily correspond in their connotations.

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid *"African-American"*, because it assumes facts not in evidence.

Comment: Personally I detest "African-American" (the term, not the people thus described).   Just as I wouldn't want to be called "European-American" (if I were a US citizen, which I'm not).

Comment: @jae: Instead, when we fill out census forms and the like, we are referred to as Caucasian, because of course all white people came from [Caucasus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasus) :/

Comment: And of course African-American and person-of-color are AE only. In BE black is perfectly OK and the main black-on-black term is Black-Briton

Comment: I wouldn't think *black* was offensive. In fact, some terms generally regarded as offensive are not always seen as offensive by the groups they are applied to. I see *Hebrew* used in Victorian novels, apparently as a euphemism for *Jew,* and I can't believe that British Jews called themselves anything other than *Jews* at the time; and I know that at least a few American Indians would rather be called Indians than Native Americans.

Comment: And who could forget the US newscaster who introduced Nelson Mandela as an "African-American"?

Answer (score 5):

Be careful when using the word 'black' in insults. Calling someone a 'bastard' is mildly offensive; calling someone a 'black bastard' is highly offensive and racist.

Comment: hehe, good to know :) as person who has never met a black person(they are not common here, I saw them, but never talk to them) I find a lot of "black pride" to be funny.

Comment: @010: in judging/understanding black pride, black nationalism, and related phenomena like political correctness, it’s important to also look at the racism in the society around/before it, that it was a reaction against.  In that context, it suddenly starts to make a whoooole lot more sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think we really ought to leave that up to the people we're assigning the label to to judge. A [2007 Gallup poll](http://www.gallup.com/poll/28816/Black-African-American.aspx) among, uhm... African/Black Americans suggests that when asked 'which term they prefer', most (61%) don't care either way, 25% prefer 'African American' and 13% 'black'. That's a 6 point increase from 1991 for 'African American' and a similar decrease for 'black'.

The term 'African American' appears to have [won acceptance in the 80ies](http://books.google.com/books?id=xoZ0POyF2YkC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=jesse+jackson+african+american+cultural+base&source=bl&ots=nEFSRzdT4Z&sig=oQ2lSr7NwQtkRTBDzLrv-c9WFIU&hl=en&ei=blsOSqudNOawtgfcu_iGCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7#v=onepage&q=jesse%20jackson%20african%20american%20cultural%20base&f=false) after Jesse Jackson began to use it, rather than the other proposal 'Afro American'.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, I missed the fact that you already mentioned the Jesse Jackson reference when skimming over previous answers.

Comment: Interestingly, Afro-Caribbean won out over African-Caribbean here in Britain.

Comment: Thank you for adding data about the preferences of the people being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I think its best just not to refer to it at all. Its a minefield, and frankly it shouldn't even be relevant information in almost all cases.

Sometimes (eg: in stories about racial issues) it is unavoidable. But if the person's ethnicity or melanin content isn't germane to the discussion, there's really no good reason to bring it up.

Answer (score 2):

I think black is less offensive than African-American, considering not all black people are from Africa and there are white people from Africa as well. I'm unsure, though. I can see it being offensive referring to someone as "that black guy," as if that is his only distinguishing characteristic.

Comment: As far as I know, the politically correct term is African-American even if it is technically incorrect.

Comment: It's hard to be offensive saying African-American. Even if the person is off Afro-Caribbean descent for example, the description is still more or less correct. It's a fine line though. Any American could call himself/herself African-American in the sense that if you go back enough generations, their ancestor is inevitably from Africa!

Comment: I think *African-American* is one of the most offensive terms (and it highlights the insular thinking of some Americans), not because there might be white Africans, but because there are plenty of black people who aren't either African or American. On an international site, why would *African-American* be offered as an alternative to *black*?

Comment: @kitukwfyer Unless you know for a fact that the OP lives in America, that's a very silly piece of advice.

Comment: @wyatt I completely agree that it's silly. I'm just saying that it seems to be the politically correct option at the moment, at least here in the US. Whether it should be is another matter entirely...I have my opinion, and I could support it logically, if it came to that, but it's just that: my opinion.

Comment: @kitukwfyer - It's the politically correct option ONLY in the US. *Black* or even *coloured* are perfectly acceptable across the entire English-speaking world, as should be recommended IMHO.

Comment: @CJM - In current US usage, "colored" is almost entirely objectionable.

Comment: @CJM: Probably don't go around saying "coloured" in the UK or the US unless you're at a far-right event, or looking to get punched.

Comment: @Marcin is correct. The only people who still say 'coloured' in the UK are racist and/or dinosaurs. I make a point of asking these people (sadly they haven't all died off yet) what colour the person they're referring to is. White is also a colour, isn't it?

Comment: @5arx - I think the term 'coloured' is old-fashioned and a bit stupid, but I don't think it's particularly racist unless the speaker continues to use it after its inappropriateness has been pointed out to them.

Comment: I would have thought socio-political and cultural changes  implicitly alerted them to this numerous times since at least the 1970s. I regard it as a casual or careless racism, not as bad say as that of the KKK or those wilfully obtuse enough to ask why the En Word is bad given that 'they call each other it all the time'. But racist nonetheless.